# Read and write to Excel in c#

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

I am creating a test framework that should read parameters from an excel sheet. I would like to be able to :

1. Get a row count of test records in the sheet
2. Get column count
3. Reference a particular cell eg A23 and read or write values to it.

I found this code on the internet. Its great but it appears to have been coded to work with a form component. I dont necessarily need to show the excel sheet on a datagrid.

This is the code I found. Its working ok but I need to add the functionalities above. Thanks for your help :)

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
...
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Book1.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0");
OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from MyObject", con);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
da.Fill(dt);
```

Comment: Did you try looking at the [MSTest's Data driven tests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243147(v=vs.80).aspx)?? They already support such scenarios.

Comment: you can get row count with : "SELECT count(*) as RowCount, * FROM "

Comment: and for Get Column count : SELECT
     COUNT(*)
FROM
     <database name>.sys.columns
WHERE
     object_id = OBJECT_ID('<database name>.<owner>.<table name>')

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add that when I run the above code am getting error:<code>TestingTips.ProgrammingTips.ReadExcelFile.ReadExcel:
System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException : The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'MyObject'.  Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly.</code>

Answer (score 1):

Count Row

```
sheet.Range["A11"].Formula = “COUNT(A1:A10)”;
```

Count Column

```
sheet.Range["A12"].Formula = “COUNT(A1:F1)”;
```

.NET Excel componetn

Answer (score 0):

you can Reference  particular cells using this code :

```
Select * from [Sheet1$A1:B10]
```

for example above code access to cell A1 to B10

see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316934)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method:

```
private DataTable LoadXLS(string filePath)
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    DataRow row;
    try
    {
        using (OleDbConnection cnLogin = new OleDbConnection())
        {
            cnLogin.ConnectionString = "provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source='" + filePath + "';Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;";

                cnLogin.Open();
                string sQuery = "SELECT * FROM  [Sheet1$]";
                table.Columns.Add("Tags", typeof(string));
                table.Columns.Add("ReplaceWords", typeof(string));
                OleDbCommand comDB = new OleDbCommand(sQuery, cnLogin);

                using (OleDbDataReader drJobs = comDB.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.Default))
                {
                    while (drJobs.Read())
                    {
                        row = table.NewRow();
                        row["Tags"] = drJobs[0].ToString();
                        row["ReplaceWords"] = drJobs[1].ToString();
                        table.Rows.Add(row);
                    }
                }
            }
            return table;
        }
```

And use like this:

```
DataTable dtXLS = LoadXLS(path);
//and do what you need
```

If you need to write into Excel you need to check this out http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264733.aspx

Answer (score 0):

an easy way to handle excel files and operations to them is the following one:

- add the `microsoft.office.interop.excel` reference to your project (Add Reference.. => search under the .NET tab => add the reference)
- create a new excel application and open the workbook:

  ```
  Excel.Application application = new Excel.Application();
  Excel.Workbook workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(workBookPath);
  Excel.Worksheet worksheet = workbook.Sheets[worksheetNumber];
  ```
- you can get the row and column count with the following lines:

  ```
  var endColumn = worksheet.Columns.CurrentRegion.EntireColumn.Count;
  var endRow = worksheet.Rows.CurrentRegion.EntireRow.Count;***
  ```
- reading values form a cell or a range of cells can be done in the following way(rowIndex is the number of the row in which the cells you want to read out are):

  ```
  System.Array values = (System.Array)worksheet.get_Range("A" + 
  rowIndex.ToString(), "D" + rowIndex.ToString()).Cells.Value;
  ```